# openstack sahara error on dashboard

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to introduce Sahara to my cloud to utilize Hadoop, and it's not going well. I tried to follow Openstack Documents but it didn't really help me. Now I'm trying to add sahara to my dashboard by command "pip install sahara-dashboard".

Sahara Dashboard is located : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/saharadashboard

original Dashboard is located : /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack-dashboard, and I added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'openstack_dashboard',
    'saharadashboard',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django_pyscss',
    'openstack_dashboard.django_pyscss_fix',
    'compressor',
    'horizon',
    'openstack_auth',
]
```

this to /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack-dashboard/setting.py.

and in : /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack-dashboard/local/local_settings.py , I added

```
    SAHARA_URL='http://localhost:8386/v1.1' 

        OPENSTACK_API_VERSIONS = {
            "data-processing": 1.1,
            "identity": 3,
            "volume": 2,
                "image": 2,
        }

     "data-processing": 1.1

   SAHARA_USE_NEUTRON=True
```

I can see Sahara managment interface on Dashboard, but I'm getting this error when I try to register image in Image Registry tab of Dashboard. Hope you don't mind Korean in the image. I ought to tell you other things are working fine in my cloud. I searched through all logs related to Sahara, and nothing comes up.

[image: image description]

I suspect that thses parts of code are where showing me the error, but don't know how to fix this issue. Please Help!

## /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/saharadashboard/image_registry/forms.py

```
 glance = importutils.import_any('openstack_dashboard.api.glance',
                                    'horizon.api.glance')

def _get_images(self, request, filter):
        try:
            images, _more = glance.image_list_detailed(request, filters=filter)
        except Exception:
            images = []
            exceptions.handle(request,
                              _("Unable to retrieve images with filter %s.") %
                              filter)
        return images

    def _get_public_images(self, request):
        filter = {"is_public": True,
                  "status": "active"}
        return self._get_images(request, filter)

    def _get_tenant_images(self, request):
        filter = {"owner": request.user.tenant_id,
                  "status": "active"}
        return self._get_images(request, filter)
```

## UPDATE

glance image-list     on controller

```
 +--------------------------------------+------------------------------+
    | ID                                   | Name                         |
    +--------------------------------------+------------------------------+
    | 28747d2b-c113-4dd3-ad44-908141461e6d | cirros                       |
    | ecb9ac84-7459-4b3b-a832-59329ae1e0ea | github-enterprise-2.6.5      |
    | 39ce8087-f95b-4204-bcee-0f084735cba9 | manila-service-image         |
    | f9a678a8-492f-481e-8c82-5d0c84f69675 | mysqlTest                    |
    | 5ae10b0d-c732-481a-944f-ca3a5a5f4915 | sahara-vanilla-latest-ubuntu |
    | f9ea4193-1a92-434d-b247-27b748feb4a1 | Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS      |
    +--------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have problem with keystone.Did you tried to restart keystone ?

Comment: Yes.. it didn't work. Trying it with CLI worked.  Dashboard config must have been set wrong..